# xsl split comma separated xml node

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have my xml as below:

```
<elementLevel>
    <ct>
      <sectionName>ABC</sectionName>
      <elementName>TNA,321</elementName>
    </ct>
    <ct>
      <sectionName>ABC</sectionName>
      <elementName>TNA,609</elementName>
    </ct>
    <ct>
      <sectionName>ABC</sectionName>
      <elementName>DF,123</elementName>
    </ct>
    <ct>
      <sectionName>ABC</sectionName>
      <elementName>ID,345</elementName>
    </ct>
</elementLevel>
```

I just want to print elementName value as two different values with comma separated.
For example TNA,321 then it should print as
`<h6><xsl:value-of select="$somevariable1"/></h6>` which will have value as 'TNA' then
`<h6><xsl:value-of select="$somevariable2"/></h6>` which will have vlaue as '321'.

Comment: Well, if you know you have only two values in each element name and you want to use that approach with variables then using e.g. `<xsl:variable name="var1" select="substring-before(., ',')"/>` should be obvious. As you have access to XSLT 2.0 based on your tags for the general case you can use `tokenize(., ',')` and then process that sequence with `for-each` to create the `h6` elements.

Comment: Please select either XSLT 1.0, or 2.0, not both. Solutions are radically different for each (and - as already pointed out - trivial in XSLT 2.0)